# #states and language in selector - best practice

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding when to use the language of the field in the selector when using #states.

I have a content type of post. It has:

- a term reference post_type that has terms such as news and learner
- an entity reference to a learner content type

Only when post_type is selected on the form as learner term do I want learner entity reference field visible.

This is my code that works :

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['field_learner']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_post_type[' . $form['field_learner']['#language'] .  ']"]' => array('value' => '14'), // (14 is the tid of term learner)
      ),
    );
    dpm($form); 
  }
}
```

I read a comment [Two gotchas](https://api.drupal.org/comment/18574#comment-18574) from the doc page on drupal_process_states that

> Fields need to have the language in the selector or the name doesn't
>   match.

I remember working with #states in the past and it worked without the language in the selector, but I think it was with a form I custom created.

Also, to work in a language agnostic manner I suppose I will have to do this rather:

```
':input[name^="field_post_type["]' => array('value' => '14'),
```

So my question is what is the best practice to do this, and will there be exceptions.